# Is there a way to detect the "back" button for Java EE web apps?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

Environment:

- Spring latest
- Using Spring Web flows 2
- Spring MVC
- Jetty server

In the situation where evoking the webflow with required parameters missing I want to print a message for the developers (I have done this by subclassing FlowController). The problem comes in when the webflow is complete and the user hits the back button. In this case I would like to redirect to another page(static).

If this were in the flow I would use a listener to perform this action, but the webflow has ended. So pressing the back button has the effect of trying to start another webflow.

Is there a way to detect the "back button" outside of the webflow?

Or any other suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than detecting the back-navigation, instead set up the last part of the webflow to not start a new flow, but instead do the redirect.

Comment: The last part of the webflow already does a redirect. Then if the user hits the back button it tries to start a new webflow without parameters. It is in the page just after the webflow is complete that if the user hits the back button I want to preform a redirect.